Why is onLocationChanged not called in my background thread although all necessary permissions are set?
I want my LocationListener to run in an own thread seperated from my ForegroundService:
Therefore I created a class called ForegroundService
class ForegroundService : Service() {
    private lateinit var notificationManager: NotificationManager
    private lateinit var notificationBuilder: NotificationCompat.Builder
    private lateinit var firstname: String
    private lateinit var lastname: String
    private lateinit var birthdate: String
    private lateinit var height: String
    private lateinit var weight: String
    private lateinit var eventname: String
    private lateinit var eventdate: String
    private lateinit var artofsport: String
    private lateinit var comment: String
    private lateinit var clothing: String
    private var speed: Float = 0.0f
    private var eventId: Int = 0
    private var distance: Double = 0.0
    private var altitude: Double = 0.0
    private var latitude: Double = 0.0
    private var longitude: Double = 0.0
    private var lap: Int = 0
    private val oldLatitude: Double = -999.0
    private val oldLongitude: Double = -999.0
    private var lazySegmentStartTimeNanos: Long = 0L
    private var lazyTotalElapsedSeconds: Long = 0L
    private var lazyFormattedTime: String = "00:00:00"
    private var movementSegmentStartTimeNanos: Long = 0L
    private var movementTotalElapsedSeconds: Long = 0L
    private var movementFormattedTime: String = "00:00:00"
    private val serviceJob = Job()
    private val serviceScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + serviceJob)
    private lateinit var wakeLock: PowerManager.WakeLock

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        loadSharedPreferences()
        //displayDatabaseContents()
        notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    }

    private fun loadSharedPreferences() {
        val sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("UserSettings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        firstname = sharedPreferences.getString("firstname", "") ?: ""
        lastname = sharedPreferences.getString("lastname", "") ?: ""
        birthdate = sharedPreferences.getString("birthdate", "") ?: ""
        height = sharedPreferences.getString("height", "") ?: ""
        weight = sharedPreferences.getString("weight", "") ?: ""
    }

    private fun acquireWakeLock() {
        val powerManager = getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
        wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "GeoTracker:ForegroundService:WakeLock")
        wakeLock.acquire()
    }

    private fun releaseWakeLock() {
        if (::wakeLock.isInitialized && wakeLock.isHeld) {
            wakeLock.release()
        }
    }

    private val database: FitnessTrackerDatabase by lazy {
        FitnessTrackerDatabase.getInstance(applicationContext)
    }

    private fun createBackgroundCoroutine() {
        serviceScope.launch {
            val customLocationListener = CustomLocationListener(applicationContext)
            customLocationListener.startDateTime = LocalDateTime.now()
            customLocationListener.startListener()
            val userId = database.userDao().getUserIdByFirstNameLastName(firstname, lastname)
            eventId = createNewEvent(database,userId)
            while (isActive) {
                // if speed is higher than some value,
                // we do not need to compare latitude and longitude (method compareLatitudeLongitude)
                // anymore because you cannot move without changing your position
                if (speed >= MIN_SPEED_THRESHOLD) {
                    showStopWatch()
                } else {
                    showLazyStopWatch()
                }
                showNotification()
                delay(1000)
            }
        }
    }

//    private fun compareLatitudeLongitude(latitude: Double, longitude: Double): Boolean {
//        val comparisonLat = oldLatitude.compareTo(latitude)
//        val comparisonLng = oldLongitude.compareTo(longitude)
//
//        return comparisonLat != 0 || comparisonLng != 0
//    }

    private fun showNotification() {
        updateNotification(
            "Activity: " + movementFormattedTime +
            "\nCovered Distance: " + String.format("%.2f", distance / 1000) + " Km" +
            "\nSpeed: " + String.format("%.2f", speed) + " km/h" +
            "\nAltitude: " + String.format("%.2f", altitude) + " meter" +
            "\nLap: " + String.format("%2d", lap) +
            "\nInactivity: " + lazyFormattedTime
        )
    }

    private fun showStopWatch() {
        if (speed >= 2.5) {
            if (movementSegmentStartTimeNanos == 0L) {
                movementSegmentStartTimeNanos = System.nanoTime()
            }

            val movementSegmentElapsedNanos = System.nanoTime() - movementSegmentStartTimeNanos
            val movementSegmentElapsedSeconds = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toSeconds(movementSegmentElapsedNanos)

            if (movementSegmentElapsedSeconds > 0) {
                movementTotalElapsedSeconds += movementSegmentElapsedSeconds
                movementSegmentStartTimeNanos = System.nanoTime()
            }

            val movementHours = (movementTotalElapsedSeconds / 3600).toInt()
            val movementMinutes = ((movementTotalElapsedSeconds % 3600) / 60).toInt()
            val movementSeconds = (movementTotalElapsedSeconds % 60).toInt()
            movementFormattedTime = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", movementHours, movementMinutes, movementSeconds)
        } else {
            movementSegmentStartTimeNanos = 0L
        }
    }

    private fun showLazyStopWatch() {
        if (speed < 2.5) {
            if (lazySegmentStartTimeNanos == 0L) {
                lazySegmentStartTimeNanos = System.nanoTime()
            }

            val lazySegmentElapsedNanos = System.nanoTime() - lazySegmentStartTimeNanos
            val lazySegmentElapsedSeconds = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toSeconds(lazySegmentElapsedNanos)

            if (lazySegmentElapsedSeconds > 0) {
                lazyTotalElapsedSeconds += lazySegmentElapsedSeconds
                lazySegmentStartTimeNanos = System.nanoTime()
            }
        } else {
            lazySegmentStartTimeNanos = 0L
        }

        // Format total inactivity time
        val lazyHours = (lazyTotalElapsedSeconds / 3600).toInt()
        val lazyMinutes = ((lazyTotalElapsedSeconds % 3600) / 60).toInt()
        val lazySeconds = (lazyTotalElapsedSeconds % 60).toInt()
        lazyFormattedTime = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", lazyHours, lazyMinutes, lazySeconds)
    }

    private fun compareLatitudeLongitude(): Boolean {
        val res: Int = when {
            oldLatitude < latitude -> -1
            oldLongitude > latitude -> 1
            else -> 0
        }
        return res == 0
    }

    private suspend fun createNewEvent(database: FitnessTrackerDatabase, userId: Int): Int {
        val newEvent = Event(
            userId = userId,
            eventName = eventname,
            eventDate = eventdate,
            artOfSport = artofsport,
            comment = comment
        )

        val eventId = database.eventDao().insertEvent(newEvent).toInt()
        println("New Event ID: $eventId")
        return eventId
    }

    private fun displayDatabaseContents() {
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val users = database.userDao().getAllUsers()
            users.forEach { user ->
                Log.d("DatabaseDebug", "User: $user")
            }
        }
    }

    // Publisher/Subscriber
    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.BACKGROUND)
    fun onLocationEvent(event: LocationEvent) {
        Log.d("ForegroundService",
            "Latitude: ${event.latitude}," +
                    " Longitude: ${event.longitude}," +
                    " Speed: ${event.speed}," +
                    " SpeedAccuracyInMeters: ${event.speedAccuracyMetersPerSecond}," +
                    " Altitude: ${event.altitude}," +
                    " HorizontalAccuracyInMeters: ${event.horizontalAccuracy}," +
                    " VerticalAccuracyInMeters: ${event.verticalAccuracyMeters}" +
                    " CoveredDistance: ${event.coveredDistance}")
        speed = event.speed
        altitude = event.altitude
        latitude = event.latitude
        longitude = event.longitude
        distance = event.coveredDistance
        lap = event.lap
        insertDatabase(database)
    }

    private fun updateNotification(newContent: String) {
        runOnUiThread {
            notificationBuilder.setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(newContent))
            notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build())
        }
    }

    private fun insertDatabase(database: FitnessTrackerDatabase) {
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val metric = Metric(
                eventId = eventId,
                heartRate = 0,
                heartRateDevice = "Chest Strap",
                speed = speed,
                distance = distance,
                cadence = 0,
                lap = lap,
                timeInMilliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis(),
                unity = "metric"
            )
            database.metricDao().insertMetric(metric)

            // Example location data
            val location = Location(
                eventId = eventId,
                latitude = latitude,
                longitude = longitude,
                altitude = altitude
            )
            database.locationDao().insertLocation(location)

            val weather = Weather(
                eventId = eventId,
                weatherRestApi = "OpenWeatherAPI",
                temperature = 0f,
                windSpeed = 0f,
                windDirection = "NE",
                relativeHumidity = 0
            )
            database.weatherDao().insertWeather(weather)

            val deviceStatus = DeviceStatus(
                eventId = eventId,
                numberOfSatellites = 8,
                sensorAccuracy = "High",
                signalStrength = "Strong",
                batteryLevel = "80%",
                connectionStatus = "Connected"
            )
            database.deviceStatusDao().insertDeviceStatus(deviceStatus)
        }
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        eventname = intent?.getStringExtra("eventName") ?: "Unknown Event"
        eventdate = intent?.getStringExtra("eventDate") ?: "Unknown Date"
        artofsport = intent?.getStringExtra("artOfSport") ?: "Unknown Sport"
        comment = intent?.getStringExtra("comment") ?: "No Comment"
        clothing = intent?.getStringExtra("clothing") ?: "No Clothing Info"

        acquireWakeLock()

        EventBus.getDefault().register(this)
        createNotificationChannel()
        createBackgroundCoroutine()

        notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("GeoTracker")
//            .setContentText("Time, covered distance, ... will be shown here!")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            //show notification on home screen to everyone
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            //without FOREGROUND_SERVICE_IMMEDIATE, notification can take up to 10 secs to be shown
            .setForegroundServiceBehavior(NotificationCompat.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_IMMEDIATE)

        val notification = notificationBuilder.build()

        startForeground(1, notification)

        return START_STICKY
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        releaseWakeLock()
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this)
        // Stop infinite loop
        serviceJob.cancel()
        // Stop foreground mode and cancel the notification immediately
        stopForeground(STOP_FOREGROUND_REMOVE)
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? = null

    private fun createNotificationChannel() {
        val channel = NotificationChannel(
            CHANNEL_ID,
            "GeoTracker",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        )
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }

    // Companion
    companion object {
        private const val CHANNEL_ID = "ForegroundServiceChannel"
        private const val MIN_SPEED_THRESHOLD: Double = 2.5
    }

    private fun runOnUiThread(action: () -> Unit) {
        if (Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()) {
            action()
        } else {
            Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(action)
        }
    }
}

Then I have my class with the implemented LocationListener, however, as soon as I turn off my screen onLocationChanged is not called anymore.
CustomLocationListener
class CustomLocationListener: LocationListener {
    private lateinit var totalDateTime: LocalDateTime
    lateinit var startDateTime: LocalDateTime
    private var context: Context
    private var locationManager: LocationManager? = null
    private var oldLatitude: Double = 99.0
    private var oldLongitude: Double = 99.0
    private var coveredDistance: Double = 0.0
    private var lapCounter : Double = 0.0
    private var lap : Int = 0
    private var averageSpeed : Double = 0.0

    constructor(context: Context) {
        this.context = context
    }

    fun startListener() {
        createLocationManager()
        createLocationUpdates()
    }

private fun createLocationUpdates() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this.context,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this.context,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
        ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED  && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this.context,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
        ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        return
    }
    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
        locationManager?.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_BETWEEN_UPDATES, this)
    }
}

    private fun createLocationManager() {
        locationManager = this.context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
    }

    override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
        location?.let {
            Log.d("CustomLocationListener", "Latitude: ${location!!.latitude} / Longitude: ${location!!.longitude}")
            coveredDistance = checkSpeedAndCalculateDistance(it)
            averageSpeed = calculateAverageSpeed(coveredDistance)
            lap = calculateLap(coveredDistance)
            EventBus.getDefault().post(LocationEvent(it.latitude, it.longitude, it.speed, it.speedAccuracyMetersPerSecond, it.altitude, it.accuracy, it.verticalAccuracyMeters, coveredDistance, lap, startDateTime, averageSpeed))
        }
    }

    private fun calculateAverageSpeed(coveredDistance: Double): Double{
        totalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now()
        var duration = Duration.between(startDateTime, totalDateTime)
        return coveredDistance / (duration.toNanos()/1_000_000_000.0)
    }

    private fun checkSpeedAndCalculateDistance(it: Location) : Double {
        if(oldLatitude!=99.0 && oldLongitude!=99.0) {
            if(checkSpeed(it.speed)) {
                coveredDistance = calculateDistance(oldLatitude, oldLongitude, it.latitude, it.longitude)
                oldLatitude = it.latitude
                oldLongitude = it.longitude
            }
        } else {
            oldLatitude = it.latitude
            oldLongitude = it.longitude
        }
        return coveredDistance
    }

    private fun calculateLap(coveredDistance: Double) : Int {
        lapCounter += coveredDistance;
        if(lapCounter>=1000) {
            lap+=1;
            lapCounter=0.0;
        }
        return lap
    }

    private fun calculateDistance(
        oldLatitude: Double,
        oldLongitude: Double,
        newLatitude: Double,
        newLongitude: Double
    ): Double {
        val result = FloatArray(1)
        Location.distanceBetween(
            //older location
            oldLatitude,
            oldLongitude,
            //current location
            newLatitude,
            newLongitude,
            result);
        coveredDistance += result[0]
        return coveredDistance
    }

    private fun checkSpeed(speed: Float): Boolean {
        return if(speed>=MIN_SPEED_THRESHOLD) {
            true
        } else {
            false
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES: Long = 1000
        private const val MIN_DISTANCE_BETWEEN_UPDATES: Float = 1f
        private const val MIN_SPEED_THRESHOLD: Double = 2.5
    }
}

I have all necessary things declared like (Battery optimization is disabled!, ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION is added too)
AndroidManifest.xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />

<service
    android:name=".service.ForegroundService"
    android:foregroundServiceType="location"
    android:exported="true" />

Maybe someone can tell me what I am missing?

You appear to be missing ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION as a permission. See the documentation for more.

@CommonsWare I added the permission and also requested it in my source code, however, it is still not working as soon as I turn off the screen.

@CommonsWare Okay, I think it is working now, I was wrong, I am sorry. I need to check it thouroughly. Thank you very much for you help!
